# Systemd Hdfs Service [hadoop] - startup

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, systemd

I have created a service that starts and stops my hdfs that is associated to my spark cluster.

the service :

```
[Unit]
Description=Hdfs service
[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/hduser
ExecStart=/opt/hadoop-2.6.4/sbin/start-service-hdfs.sh
ExecStop=/opt/hadoop-2.6.4/sbin/stop-service-hdfs.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The problem is when i start the service, it starts and stops just after been started !! :) 
I think the problem is the type of the service, I don't really know what type to choose ...

Thank you. 
Best regards

Comment: What does your log(s) say? Both journalctl and hdfs log (I don't know where you placed it)

Comment: Have you formatted the namenode while installation

Answer (score 7):

Threre are some issues in your config, that is why it is not working.

I'm running `hadoop 2.7.3, hive 2.1.1, ubuntu 16.04` under `hadoop` user

`HADOOP_HOME` is `/home/hadoop/envs/dwh/hadoop/`

```
[Unit]
Description=Hadoop DFS namenode and datanode
After=syslog.target network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target network-online.target
Requires=network-online.target

[Service]
User=hadoop
Group=hadoop
Type=forking
ExecStart=/home/hadoop/envs/dwh/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh
ExecStop=/home/hadoop/envs/dwh/hadoop/sbin/stop-dfs.sh
WorkingDirectory=/home/hadoop/envs/dwh
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Environment=HADOOP_HOME=/home/hadoop/envs/dwh/hadoop
TimeoutStartSec=2min
Restart=on-failure
PIDFile=/tmp/hadoop-hadoop-namenode.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Checklist:

- user and user group is set
- service type is `fork`
- pid file is set, and this is actual pid that `start-dfs.sh` creates
- environment variables are correct

Answer (score 0):

an alternative stoppable oneshot service which contains hdfs and yarn altogether

```
[Unit]
Description=Hadoop DFS namenode and datanode & yarn service
After=syslog.target network-online.target

[Service]
User=hadoop
Group=hadoop
Type=oneshot
ExecStartPre=/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.10.1/sbin/start-dfs.sh
ExecStart=/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.10.1/sbin/start-yarn.sh
ExecStop=/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.10.1/sbin/stop-dfs.sh
ExecStopPost=/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.10.1/sbin/stop-yarn.sh
WorkingDirectory=/home/hadoop
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```