# systemd service for hadoop start-dfs.sh

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs, systemd

I am having trouble getting Hadoop dfs running as a system service on Ubuntu18.04.
Running start-dfs.sh from the terminal works fine, but running as a systemd service fails.

I also tried the example here ([Systemd Hdfs Service [hadoop] - startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398280/systemd-hdfs-service-hadoop-startup)) but it fails.

The service file..

```
[Unit]
Description=Hadoop DFS namenode and datanode
After=syslog.target network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target network-online.target
Requires=network-online.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
Type=forking
ExecStart=/opt/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh
ExecStop=/opt/hadoop/sbin/stop-dfs.sh
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_251
Environment=SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
Environment=HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop
Environment=HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop
Environment=HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=/opt/hadoop/lib/native"
Environment=YARN_HOME=/opt/hadoop
Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/hadoop/lib/native
TimeoutStartSec=2min
#Restart=on-failure
PIDFile=/tmp/hadoop-ubuntu-namenode.pid
RestartSec= 30
StartLimitInterval=350
StartLimitBurst=10
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The error...

```
ubuntu@sc:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo service hadoop-dfs status
● hadoop-dfs.service - Hadoop DFS namenode and datanode
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/hadoop-dfs.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Wed 2020-10-14 14:28:19 UTC; 8s ago
  Process: 4992 ExecStart=/opt/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 14 14:28:00 sc systemd[1]: Starting Hadoop DFS namenode and datanode...
Oct 14 14:28:01 sc start-dfs.sh[4992]: Starting namenodes on [localhost]
Oct 14 14:28:06 sc start-dfs.sh[4992]: localhost: starting namenode, logging to /opt/hadoop-2.8.5/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-namenode-sc.out
Oct 14 14:28:11 sc start-dfs.sh[4992]: localhost: starting datanode, logging to /opt/hadoop-2.8.5/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-datanode-sc.out
Oct 14 14:28:12 sc start-dfs.sh[4992]: Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
Oct 14 14:28:17 sc start-dfs.sh[4992]: 0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /opt/hadoop-2.8.5/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-secondarynamenode-sc.out
Oct 14 14:28:19 sc systemd[1]: hadoop-dfs.service: New main PID 6948 does not belong to service, and PID file is not owned by root. Refusing.
Oct 14 14:28:19 sc systemd[1]: hadoop-dfs.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Oct 14 14:28:19 sc systemd[1]: Failed to start Hadoop DFS namenode and datanode.
```

---

After setting up a dedicated user and running just the namenode

```
● hadoop-dfs.service - Hadoop DFS namenode and datanode
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/hadoop-dfs.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-10-14 15:59:35 UTC; 5s ago
  Process: 12633 ExecStart=/opt/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 14 15:59:31 sc systemd[1]: Starting Hadoop DFS namenode and datanode...
Oct 14 15:59:31 sc hadoop-daemon.sh[12633]: starting namenode, logging to /opt/hadoop-2.8.5/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-sc.out
Oct 14 15:59:35 sc systemd[1]: hadoop-dfs.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 14 15:59:35 sc systemd[1]: hadoop-dfs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 14 15:59:35 sc systemd[1]: Failed to start Hadoop DFS namenode and datanode.
```

Comment: `PID file is not owned by root`... I would try not using `User=ubuntu` since you would normally be running start-dfs as sudo, however, you should also have dedicated users and groups for hadoop daemons

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer. Yes normally I would created a dedicated user & group, but wouldn't the same issue occur as ubuntu is just another user (albeit with sudo privileges)? When file `/tmp/hadoop-ubuntu-namenode.pid` is created it is owned by the whatever user `User=` is set to, so I'm confused as to why having the pid file owned by a different user would resolve the `not owned by root` error. Can you please explain why it would make a difference?

Comment: I'm just pointing out that the error appears to expect the PID owned not by the user you've currently set it to

Comment: Also, I would use separate services for the namenode and datanode, which can be ran by the `hadoop` command directly

Comment: Ok I setup a dedicated user, and ran only namenode `ExecStart=/opt/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode` however I am still seeing an error. Please see the update in the main post

Comment: Ahh never mind I was missing folder `/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/dfs/name`. The namenode then ran but the service command hung as `hadoop-daemon.sh` is not a forking process. I changed `Type=simple` and it now runs. Nice! I'll work on the rest and accept the answer once I've confirmed it is all working.  Still it is strange that other people have been using start-dfs.sh successfully with systemd

Comment: Not sure, but a cloudera/hortonworks cluster does have individual services.

Comment: i gave up on ubuntu. use redhat centos.

Comment: separate services for the namenode and datanode was what fixed the issue. Thanks for your help @OneCricketeer, post it as an answer and I'll mark it answered

Answer (score 0):

Try this service definition. It worked for me.

```
[Unit]
Description=Hadoop DFS namenode and datanode
After=syslog.target network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target network-online.target
Requires=network-online.target

[Service]
User=hadoop
Group=hadoop
Type=forking
ExecStart=/app/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh
ExecStop=/app/hadoop/sbin/stop-dfs.sh
WorkingDirectory=/app/hadoop
TimeoutStartSec=1min
# Restart=on-failure
Restart=no
RestartSec=30
RemainAfterExit=yes
# PIDFile=/tmp/hadoop-hadoop-namenode.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```